# How to colonize in Ogame?

Tags: ogame

Which researched technologies are required to colonize a planet in OGame? 
Which planets are recommended to colonize?

Comment: For reference here's the [(unoficial) wiki page](http://ogame.wikia.com/wiki/Colony). I think however that the information there is quite scattered (hence, an answer here is beneficial). As OGame has evolved a lot since the last time I played, I'm not comfortable writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are playing in a [redesigned universe](http://ogame.wikia.com/wiki/Redesigned_Universe), such as Electra, you need to research [Astrophysics](http://ogame.wikia.com/wiki/Astrophysics) in order to colonize a planet, given that you have the technology to build [Colony Ships](http://ogame.wikia.com/wiki/Colony_Ship). Every 2 level of astrophysics will let you have another colony.

As for the planet recommendation, I'd suggest you take a look at [colonizing in redesigned universes](http://ogame.wikia.com/wiki/Colonizing_in_Redesigned_Universes) for redesigned universes or [colonization](http://ogame.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Size) for old universes for choosing a planet to colonize.

[image]

Colder planets (as you go to 15th position) will have a higher deuterium outcome while having smaller sizes around 70-90 while hotter planets (closer to 1st position) will have higher energy output from solar satellites, suitable for [Graviton](http://ogame.wikia.com/wiki/Graviton_Technology) research, however, again, shrinking in size just like colder planets. 8th position appears to have the largest average size of all planets.

<sub>Note: I'm not sure if all the universes are now considered 'redesigned' as of september 2010 according to [this wiki page](http://ogame.wikia.com/wiki/Redesigned_Universe). You have to find out yourself if your universe is considered to be redesigned.</sub>